# Append without last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sub">a</div>

    <span id="add">add</span>
</div>            

$('#add').click(function(){
   $('#container').append('<div class="sub">a</div>');
})
```

This append element to #container on bottom. How can i add this element on bottom without last element(#add)? I would like have always #add on bottom.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nk67d/

Comment: are you using `#add` as a placeholder? how do you mean "without last element(#add)"? EDIT: ah, got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("#add").prepend('<div class="sub">a</div>');
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nk67d/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/), it adds the markup before the matched elements.

```
$('#add').before('<div class="sub">a</div>');
```

To complete the answer:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
   $(this).before('<div class="sub">a</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [insertBefore(target)](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/);

```
$('<div class="sub">a</div>').insertBefore("#add");
```

you could also use [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method to insert the `div` immediately preceding the add button

```
$('#add').click(function(){
   $(this).before('<div class="sub">a</div>');  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#add').click(function(){
   $(this).before('<div class="sub">a</div>');
})
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nk67d/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#container #add').before('<div class="sub">abcd</div>');
})
```

Comment: Assuming it's because your selector `#container #add` can just be `$(this)`. Either way, upvoted.